# Sequelize query multiple times

Tags: node.js, database, search, sequelize.js, querying

I'm trying to improve the search on my website, this is how it currently looks (I use NodeJS, Sequelize and PostgreSQL):

```
db.food.findAll({
        where: {
            nameFood: {
                $iLike: '%' + queryName + '%'
            }
        }
    }).then(function (foods) {
        foods.sort(compareFood);

        res.json(foods);
    }, function (e) {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
```

I think it is pretty self explanatory, but if something isn't clear just ask me on the comments.

Now, this search algorithm takes into consideration the WHOLE parameter, so searching for "chicken eggs" would return nothing since on my database they're saved as "eggs".

My idea for a quick improvement would be to split the query looking for spaces and then query each keyword, something like:

```
var keywords = queryName.split(' ');
```

With that I have the keywords, now how can I query a variable number of times and join the result in an array to be returned like the one in foods?

I checked the documentation and some questions in here but couldn't find anything, any help is appreciated, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$or` property for querying anything matching "eggs" or "chicken".

Here's an example:

```
// split queryName by spaces
var qry = queryName.split(' ');

// convert each item into a $iLike object
// ['chicken', 'eggs'] -> [{ $iLike: '%chicken%' }, { $iLike: '%eggs%' }]
qry = qry.map(function(item) {
  return {
    $iLike: '%' + item + '%';
  };
});

db.food.findAll({
    where: {
        nameFood: { $or: qry }
    }
}).then(function (foods) {
    foods.sort(compareFood);

    res.json(foods);
}).catch(function (e) {
    res.status(500).send();
});
```

Hope that answers your question but before you go I've also got a nice tip for you that you might find helpful.

One of them is using the `.catch` function for receiving any errors. Rather then using `.then` for both results and errors, you can leave `.then` to handling the results and `.catch` to handling the errors.

```
db.food.findAll()
  .then(function(results) {

   })
   .catch(function(err) {

   });
```

instead of

```
db.food.findAll()
  .then(function(results) {

   }, function(err) {

   });
```